# Visual Studio 2012: change javascript comment style

Tags: javascript, comments, visual-studio-2012, code-formatting, spaces

When I comment out a line in a javascript file in Visual Studio using the shortcut or toolbar button, there is no space before the comment text.

```
//the way comments are currently formatted
```

I would like to have a space automatically added before the comment text.

```
// the way I want it
```

How can I change the default comment formatting?

Comment: It would be useful to be able to change this because stylecop complains if you don't have a space or put 4 slashes in front of commented out code as per https://github.com/DotNetAnalyzers/StyleCopAnalyzers/blob/master/documentation/SA1005.md.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think so you can do this out of box. BUT you can obviously create a visual studio extension for that